# OCaml Compile Error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstr

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ocaml, nltk

I am trying to compile the source code of [MEGAM](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/megam/) Ocaml library on an Ubuntu 64 machine.

I have OCaml installed (v 3.12.1), using `sudo apt-get install ocaml`.

I am having an issue when running the "make" command in the terminal on the unzipped source code, with OCaml returning the error:

```
/user/bin/ld: cannot find -lstr
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The makefile is producing the following two commands:

```
 ocamldep *.ml > .depend
```

No error when run

> ocamlc -g -custom  -o megam str.cma -cclib -lstr bigarray.cma -cclib -lbigarray unix.cma -cclib -lunix -I /usr/lib/ocaml/caml fastdot_c.c fastdot.cmo intHashtbl.cmo arry.cmo util.cmo data.cmo bitvec.cmo cg.cmo wsemlm.cmo bfgs.cmo pa.cmo perceptron.cmo radapt.cmo kernelmap.cmo abffs.cmo main.cmo

Throws the error above when run.

I've tried removing the -lstr from the compile command, it stopped throwing that particular error but started throwing another error (`Reference to undefined global 'Bigarray'`), which is making me thing it might all be something I missed during the OCaml installation, some kind of PATH or reference I needed to set.

Any help is really appreciated, even if its just a shot in the dark, as am really struggling to come up with anything!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The instructions given here](http://church.cs.virginia.edu/genprog/index.php/FAQ#I_get_the_error:_cil_file_.22is_not_a_compiled_interface.22._What_do_I_do.3F)  allow me to compile with no error. It boils down to:

```
locate libcamlstr
```

which tells me that libcamlstr can be found in `/usr/lib/ocaml` (YMMV), so I do:

```
cd /usr/lib/ocaml
sudo ln -s libcamlstr.a libstr.a
```

Then I'm able to compile the project:

```
cd /usr/local/src/cil
make clean && ./configure && make
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just change the makefile from

```
-lstr
```

to

```
-lcamlstr
```

Answer (score 2):

See the last comment in this bug in the OCaml bug tracker:

[Bug 5247](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5247)